# Numpy matrix red dot path visualization

Tags: python, image, numpy, matrix, visualization

I have a numpy matrix fill of 0. On each iteration a go along the principal diagonal putting 1. Instead of see just 1 I want to display a numpy matrix with red dot/square in the principal diagonal.

I want also see the same matrix updated in each position at runtime instead of display n different matrix

Answer (score 0):

while printing don't just print but rather use this code

```
# Class of different styles
class style():
    BLACK = '\033[30m'
    RED = '\033[31m'
    GREEN = '\033[32m'
    YELLOW = '\033[33m'
    BLUE = '\033[34m'
    MAGENTA = '\033[35m'
    CYAN = '\033[36m'
    WHITE = '\033[37m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    RESET = '\033[0m'

for a in range(rows):
    for b in range(cols):
        if mat[a][b] == 1:
            print(style.RED + str('x'), end='')
        else:
            print(str('0'), end='')
    print('\n', end='') # print a new line since we skip them in the for loop
```

Comment: It's full red, you must add style.RESET after the end=''. Instead if I want to see the progression of the print??? for for each iteration I want to see the matrix, not only at the end